# Where is located Gstreamer cache when working in development environment?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm working with [Gstreamer](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer) in a [development environment](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer#development-environment-target) and I want to delete the registration cache in order to remove some libraries from the blacklist. When working with the system environment I usually do it by deleting the file at `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/`.

Where is the equivalent file when working in development?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the gstreamer

`~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/`